# How can solidity functions be internal yet have no default?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

In the Solidity docs, it states that

> Visibility has to be specified explicitly for functions defined in contracts, they do not have a default.

Yet it also says that

> By default, function types are internal, so the internal keyword can be omitted.

It seems to be saying that functions have no visibility default and their function type is `internal` by default. But what is the difference between a function type and function visibility? I see `internal` and `external` included under both function types and function visibility within the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There are four types of function visibility in Solidity: `external` , `internal` , `private`, and `public`.

The types described the different visibilities (`external` , `internal` , `private`, and `public`) that can be declared in a Solidity function or state variable.

The visibilities described the different accessibility (`public` functions can be accessed everywhere, `external` functions can be only accessed outside of a contract, `internal` functions can only be accessed within a contract or those derived from it, and `private` functions can only be accessed within the same contract) of these visibilities.

Although it seems to be saying that functions have no visibility default and their function type is internal by default, it is a recommended practice that you declare visibilities in all your functions in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. There are 2 types of functions and 4 kinds of visibilities. The 2 function types are `internal` and `external` which are the different ways a function can be called. `external` functions are visible externally and so are `public` functions. A `public` function may be called both `internal`ly or `external`ly.

Comment: No, there are 4 types of functions and 4 kinds of visibilities. The 4 types are internal, external, public, and private. The 4 types are also internal, external, public, and private. My point is to clarify between types and visibilities, although the types and visibilities may overlap.

Comment: I am relatively confident there are only two types of functions. In the docs, it states `Function types
come in two flavours - internal and external functions`. I believe the different types refer to how the function may be called while visibility relates to where they are accessible.